# Extending Picard Lindelof to PDE Enviroment

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I've been working on a new method, being successful on homogeneous cases, to deduce analytical functions under certain conditions, and along this method, I find first-order partial differential along all the directions define in the space, letting me write the Total derivative, and I did question my self about what happens with the existence and uniqueness over this PDE's, because on ODE's does exist the Picard-Lindelof Theorem, but I can not find anything similar to that, therefore I began to think on extending the Picard-Lindelof Theorem, but before going this path I want to ask if there is an impossibility to achieve this goal?, If does exist wich one?, and which one might you think would be the biggest wall to face along this path?, and if it's already done I really would appreciate some source to look for it.

It is not quite a specific question perse, but reading about some opinions from people who work on the issue, will help me clarify some ideas before facing it, therefore I wait for your honest opinion on the matter.

Comment: A little clarification when I say "I find first-order partial differential equations..." I mean that I find an equation for each direction independent from the behavior of the other directions, therefore I have a system of equations that describe all the directions plausible in the domain the PDE is define.

Comment: In general there is no such result for PDEs. Also see [Lewy's example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970121?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) of a smooth linear PDE without  solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I will read the paper about the example and see how this affect my hypothesis.